# Display collapse content one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found some really helpful tutorial to help me use javascript to expand and collapse content, but now I can't figure out how to make it only expand one at a time... So that when one div is expanded, if you click to expand another one, it collapses the first one. Any ideas? Here is the tutorial that i have followed

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="collapsible"> Expand </button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you added that code as a run-able snippet.
Also, can you provide html which contains multiple sections instead of just one?

Comment: So select the one with an active class and remove it if it is not the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all the `<div class="content">` and then set each of those to `display: none`. Snippet below:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    
    //add new code here
    var contents = document.querySelectorAll('div.content')
    contents.forEach((content) => {
     content.style.display = "none"
    })
    
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible"> Expand </button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible"> Expand </button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Some content2</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps